# Javascript - Listener

Tags: javascript

Если бы у Вас была необходимость в "прослушке" переменной на событие ее изменения.
Например:

```
var a = 5;
var a = a + 2;
// а - изменилась, выполняем какую-либо функцию
```

Как бы Вы поступили в данном случае?

Comment: Не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно в таймере, например, каждые 0.7 секунд, проверять значение переменной. Создать глобальную переменную(например, pred), а в таймере в неё записывать текущее значение переменной "а". И наконец, сверять переменную "pred" с текущим значением "a":

```
var a = 5;
pred = a;
window.setInterval(function(){if(a!=pred) alert('');  pred=a},700);
```

Comment: Так сойдет?

Comment: Эм, нет. Зачем такая нагрузка. Решил сделать немного иначе. Просто сделал переменную приватную, а к ней привинтил Сеттер и геттер. При изменении переменной сеттером идет вызов функции. Тот же листенер :) Впринципе, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: О какой нагрузке идет речь? Вы о чем?